Is there Any way to get public ip address without using any packages (EXPO)
im using expos 'expo-network' package,
i want to remove unnecessary packages from package.json
any workaround for getting public ip address
i tried

expo-network : expo-network
(not works in expo)  : react-native-network-info



Try to use ipfy API
request : GET https://api.ipify.org?format=json
response :{ "ip": "<public ip of requester>" }

For more information see
ipify docs

there is no usage limit

WARN! : it will introduce a new async request, So Handle With Care !


